# Dynamic headers in ActiveModelAdapter based upon my routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to dynamically set my ActiveModelAdapter header depending upon my routes so that I can optimize the data payload from backend.

I need to set the header dynamically for my **index** and **show** routes as

```
App.ResourceAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
  host: "localhost:3000"
  headers:
    # For Index routes
    "Accept": "application/vnd.app+json; version=1"
    # OR For Show routes
    "Accept": "application/vnd.app-detailed+json; version=1"
```

Ember doc proposes use of computed headers but how can I get the routing context in my adapter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your current route  via `App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentRouteName")`

according to [doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_get-current-route-name-path)

so then up to you to do something like :

```
    headers : function(){
         var location = App.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentRouteName") ;
          if(location==="resource"){
            return  "Accept": "application/vnd.app+json; version=1"
          }else{
            return "Accept": "application/vnd.app+json; version=1"
          }
    }.property().volatile()
```

You need to adapt to your needs of course :)

Comment: instead of getting the private `App.__container__` you can add `this.inject('adapter:segment', 'application', 'controller:application');` in your Ember.Application object in the `init` function :)

Comment: @andrusieczko yes you can :) in his case he would in fact inject to 'adapter:resource' or to adapter itself it's may be more the ember way.

Comment: yes, I meant `this.inject('adapter:resource', 'application', 'controller:application');`, thanks for spotting that!